# Слайдер с миниатюрами и скролл-баром.

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста слайдер с миниатюрами с возможностью настройки горизонтального скролл-бара. На примере вот такого: [image: Slider]

Просьба не предлагать слайдер Swiper из-за его странной работы скролла - в моем примере, бегунок просто перескакивает с последнего изображения на последнее. 
Стоит ли вообще искать подходящий плагин или лучше попробовать написать самому?